# $.get not get HTML <script tag, making it difficult to display ReCaptcha.GetHtml

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, recaptcha

I use JQueryUI to display the form in a dialog, however as it has `@ReCaptcha.GetHtml` tags scripts, the `$.get` does not bring these tags.

**It returns:**

```
<noscript>
         <iframe frameborder="0" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?xxxx" height="300px" width="500px"> </ iframe>
         <br /> <br />
         <textarea cols="40" name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3"> </ textarea>
         <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge" />
     </ noscript>
```

How do I make an ajax call and return to use these scripts @ReCaptcha.GetHtml

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250015/asp-net-mvc-3-jquery-ajax-get-return-nonscript-recaptcha-instead-of-actual) here on stackoverflow but he continued on his course.

Answer (score 0):

If js is off, you cannot call `$.get` or another js function, respectively method doesn't return `noscript`

Comment: js is on, it usually returns the HTML! The problem is that scripts in the HTML tags it does not return!